# How can I increase RAM capacity in Colab pro+?

Tags: google-colaboratory

How can I  increase RAM capacity in Colab pro + ?
I need RAM > 35 GB but Colab pro+ provide only 12 GB

Regards
Chaiyan S.

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Having the same issue.

Even after choosing the "high-ram" runtime I still get only 12Gb of RAM on Colab Pro+ .

And they're charging $50/ month for this, total ripoff.

Answer (score 0):

To set your notebook preference to use a high-memory runtime, select the Runtime > 'Change runtime type' menu, and then select High-RAM in the Runtime shape dropdown.

Then you can check it by running following code in the cell:

```
from psutil import virtual_memory
ram_gb = virtual_memory().total / 1e9
print('Your runtime has {:.1f} gigabytes of available RAM\n'.format(ram_gb))

if ram_gb < 20:
  print('Not using a high-RAM runtime')
else:
  print('You are using a high-RAM runtime!')
```

Comment: Thanks Raha, but it doesn't work. I already did same  your suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure that your account has been upgraded to pro+? Sometimes you have several google account and you connected with non-pro one. This is so weird. if the problem still remains, you can contact Google teams.